# Find specific word in column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008.

My tables are :

**Location**

```
------------------------
 Id  |  LocationName
------------------------
  1  |  Bodakdev
  2  |  Thaltej Road
  3  |  Andheri East
  4  |  Noida Sector 2
```

**Company**

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   CId  |  Address                                            | LocationId
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   11   |   301, GNFC Infotower, Bodakdev,                    |    NULL
   12   |   307/308,Arundeep Complex                          |    NULL
   13   |   7 Krishana Dyeing Compund, Nagardas rd., Andheri  |    NULL
   14   |   B-23 ,Ground Floor,Sector 2                       |    NULL
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Currently `LocationId` in the `Company` table are null. If `Address` contains any location name then update `LocationId`.

For example, Address of CID - 11 contains `Bodakdev` then update LocationId 1, second example, Address of CID - 13 contains `Andheri` word then update LocationId 3.

Required output :

```
  CId  |  Address                                            | LocationId
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   11   |   301, GNFC Infotower, Bodakdev,                    |    1
   12   |   307/308,Arundeep Complex                          |    NULL
   13   |   7 Krishana Dyeing Compund, Nagardas rd., Andheri  |    3
   14   |   B-23 ,Ground Floor,Sector 2                       |    4
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried using below query

```
SELECT   
   (LEN(Address) - LEN(REPLACE(Address, LocationName, '')) ) / LEN(LocationName)
```

if `Address` contains Location Name then it will return number of occurrences otherwise it return 0.

But it will not give correct output. How can I do this? Thanks. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to update the rows in the database or would a query producing the output be sufficient?

Comment: @ojblass I want to update rows in database but first i m trying to get the Id of Location.

Comment: why don't you use 'like' keyword ?

Comment: @DoobyInc I have tried using `LIKE` but it not gives me expected output.

Comment: What is the data type of column "Address" .. Is text or varchar.

Comment: @Selvam Data type of "Address" is Varchar.

Comment: If datatype is varchar then like should be wroked, refer below my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following Query :

1.STEP1 : make one function which can split the sting by any character and return the output in table format .

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

2.STEP2 : use following query to get your desire output .

```
    DECLARE @LOCATION AS TABLE (ID INT ,NAME VARCHAR(MAX))  
DECLARE @COMPANY AS TABLE (CID INT , ADDRESS VARCHAR(MAX) , LOCATIONID INT)     

INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES(1,'Bodakdev')
INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES(2,'Thaltej Road')
INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES(3,'Andheri East')
INSERT INTO @LOCATION VALUES(4,'Noida Sector 2')

INSERT INTO @COMPANY VALUES(11,'301, GNFC Infotower, Bodakdev,' , NULL)
INSERT INTO @COMPANY VALUES(12,'307/308,Arundeep Complex' , NULL)
INSERT INTO @COMPANY VALUES(11,'7 Krishana Dyeing Compund, Nagardas rd., Andheri' , NULL)
INSERT INTO @COMPANY VALUES(11,'B-23 ,Ground Floor,Sector 2' , NULL)

UPDATE @Company
SET
LOCATIONID = B.ID
FROM @COMPANY AS A , @LOCATION AS B 
WHERE 
1 = CASE WHEN 
            (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM FNSPLIT(B.NAME , ' ')
                WHERE A.ADDRESS LIKE '%' + ITEM +  '%'
            ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

This is the one way to do it . we can do it using full text searching also.

Comment: But in what particular way have you used `LIKE`? Exactly like this?

Comment: did't get your question . can you explain it more .

Comment: @HirenDhaduk I have updated my question. I hope you can now understand what i want?

Comment: I modified my answer . I checked it it gives me proper output .